# R - how to get a value of a multi-dimensional array by a vector of indices

Tags: r

Let's say I have a multi-dimensional array called `pi`, and its number of dimensions isn't known until the runtime:

```
dims <- rep(3, dim_count)
pi <- array(0, dims)
```

As you can see the dimension count depends on `dim_count`. How do I retrieve a value from the array when I have a vector of the indexes? For example when I have:

```
dim_count <- 5
indexes <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

I want to retrieve

```
pi[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Is there a short, effective and hopefully elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Making use of a little known usage of `[`:

> When indexing arrays by `[` a single argument `i` can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of `x`; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of `i`.

you can simply do:

```
pi[matrix(indexes, 1)]
```

Answer (score 10):

`do.call("[",...)` seems to work.

```
indexes <- c(1,2,3,3,3)
pi[1,2,3,3,3] <- 17  ## so we know if we succeeded or not
do.call("[",c(list(pi),as.list(indexes)))
```

Note that your example wouldn't work -- your dimensions were all 3, but some of your index elements were >3 ...

Comment: yeah, the particular example was partially made up to show the smallest significant piece of code and I didn't notice it :)

Comment: Oh, you were somewhat quicker than me here. +1.

Answer (score 4):

`do.call()` is an option:

```
dim_count <- 5
indexes <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3)
dims <- rep(3, dim_count)
pi <- array(seq_len(prod(dims)), dims)

do.call(`[`, c(list(x = pi), as.list(indexes)))
```

Which gives:

```
> do.call(`[`, c(list(x = pi), as.list(indexes)))
[1] 202
> pi[1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[1] 202
```

The tricky bit is getting the list of arguments in the right format. `pi` should be the first argument to `"["` (or named as argument `x`, see `?"["`), whilst we want each element of `indexes` itself to be a component of the supplied list, not a vector within that list. Hence the convoluted `c(list(x = pi), as.list(indexes))`.

An alternative way to construct the argument list which might be easier to follow is:

```
ARGS <- vector("list", length = dim_count + 1)
ARGS[[1]] <- pi
ARGS[2:length(ARGS)] <- indexes
do.call("[", ARGS)
```

which gives

```
> do.call("[", ARGS)
[1] 202
> pi[1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[1] 202
```