# How to get a value of a multi-dimensional array by an INCOMPLETE vector of indices

Tags: r

This question is very similar to
[R - how to get a value of a multi-dimensional array by a vector of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865337/r-how-to-get-a-value-of-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-a-vector-of-indices)

I have:

```
dim_count <- 5
dims <- rep(3, dim_count)
pi <- array(1:3^5, dims)
```

I want to get an entire line, but with an automatic building of the address of this line.
For example, I would like to get:

```
pi[1,,2,2,3]
##  [1] 199 202 205
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a sequence covering the whole dimension in the appropriate slot:

```
do.call("[",list(pi,1,1:dim(pi)[2],2,2,3))
```

By the way, defining a variable called `pi` is a little dangerous (I know this was inherited from the previous question) -- suppose you tried a few lines later to compute the circumference of a circle as `pi*diameter` ...