# R - Indexing Array using Array

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

Lets assume I have an array of `dim(x) <- c(3,3,3)`.  I also have a df or matrix with two** columns containing index combinations that I need.

When I pass `x[df[[1]],df[[2]],]` I get a VERY large array which I then need to go through and take the diagonal of using the apply function.  This is very memory and time inefficient.  Is there some sort of shortcut (without using `for` loops) to index an array so that it would return the vector of values that the `df` asks for.

Trivial Example:

```
`a <- array(1:27,dim = c(3,3,3))
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,2,1,3,2),c(2,3,2,1,3,2))`
```

In this example, I would want to pass something like "`a[df[[1]],df[[2]],]`"
and get something like this (or transposed):

`.        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
    [1,]    4    8    5    1    9    5
    [2,]   13   17   14   10   18   14
    [3,]   22   26   23   19   27   23`

When I pass that function now, I get a 3-d array of `dim = c(6,6,3)` as apposed to the more helpful `dim = c(6,3)`.  I can easily take `apply(result, 3,diag)` to get what I want, but when df>>6 it takes up a lot of space (like 750GB of space and throws warnings, errors and stops execution before beginning)

Comment: `x = 1:27; dim(x) <- c(3,3,3); x[cbind(1,2,3)]` You can see more on this in `?Extract`

Comment: Please read `help("[")`: "A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one column for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then selects a single element of the array, and the result is a vector"

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10865337/

Comment: Frank: the closely related was almost exactly what I needed.  I'm going to try to take a slight variation off of that , thank you!  A slight difference now is what if I need to access `x[df[[1]],df[[2]],]` and get that array back?  I tried and R crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
temp <- array(1:27, dim=c(3,3,3))
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3), c=c(1,2,3))

temp[cbind(df[[1]], df[[2]], df[[3]])]
[1]  1 14 27
```

This is sometimes referred to as matrix indexing.

To query by two of the dimensions and leave the third one open, you might just use the regular matrix subsetting: For example, to select the the first and second row and second column for each of the "z" dimension matrices, you could use something like `temp[1:2, 2,]` or from your dataset:

```
temp[1:2, 2,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4   13   22
[2,]    5   14   23

temp[df[[1]][1:2], df[[2]][2], ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4   13   22
[2,]    5   14   23
```

Which are of course identical.